# Redirect specific sub domains to https in .htaccess with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to test out SSL on my server starting with a TEST environment. The rules seem to work on my local, but when I commit to my test server I get the "Too many redirects" error.

Here are the relevant rewrite conditions/rules i have:

```
# Send non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Send test.mysite.com to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.test\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The goal is to send www.test.mysite.com and test.mysite.com both to https://www.test.mysite.com

Comment: Those rules look fine to me... Maybe some other rules interfering here? Rules in the real server configuration or in other dynamic configuration files that (accidentally) redirect _back_ to http?

Comment: If you can't find anything, then I suggest you enable rewrite logging (see the official documentation of the rewriting module for that). It allows you to examine each step of what is actually going on inside your rewrite engine.

Answer (score 0):

I've uncommented the line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.test\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

And it seems to be working now in private browsers. Does this make the www line unnecessary?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```